# Having Trouble Playing Video Through OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, video

So I am trying to make OpenCV play the [Megamind.avi](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data) video for me, but everytime I run my code it gives me this error:

```
2016-12-29 19:07:39.916 process[17091:382843] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92e800db __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffa7b12a2a objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92d9c4fb -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 203
    3   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x000000010b2f0270 _ZN13CvCaptureFileC2EPKc + 350
    4   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x000000010b2eece2 _Z32cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundationPKc + 34
    5   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x000000010b2e27de cvCreateFileCapture + 14
    6   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x000000010b2e2a8e _ZN2cv12VideoCapture4openERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE + 64
    7   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x000000010b2e28ee _ZN2cv12VideoCaptureC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE + 42
    8   process                             0x000000010adcd517 main + 215
    9   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffa83f4255 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

It also occurs whenever I run the sample [OpenCV video reading and writing program](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html), so I'm not sure if something is screwed up on my end or has there been a change in OpenCV that broke some methods.
Here is my code for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  const string source = "Megamind.avi";
  VideoCapture inputVideo(source);
  if (!inputVideo.isOpened())
  {
    cout  << "Could not open the input video" << source << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  cout  << "read!" << endl;
  namedWindow("Video",1);
  for(;;){
      Mat frame;
      inputVideo >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
      imshow("Video", frame);
      if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
  }
  VideoWriter outputVideo;
  return 0;
}
```

Also if I apply the program to the vtest.avi video file from the same github repo, it returns this error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /tmp/opencv-20161020-7399-1yrk4nm/opencv-2.4.13.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 261
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv-20161020-7399-1yrk4nm/opencv-2.4.13.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

I read up online to add this if statement in the for loop:

```
if (!frame.empty()) {
      imshow("window", frame);
}
```

but it results in just an empty window. Not sure if this changes my issue at all.

Comment: The exception seems to indicate that you are accessing an index outside of the bounds of an array. Is it possible that you are not calling the program with the required source argument?

Comment: I changed the arg to location of the actual file but it doesn't seem to fix anything. I'm pretty sure the error is something related to the for loop, as it adding that caused the error.